# I don't know where to begin with this functions question (one-to-one, onto)

Tags: functions, discrete-mathematics

a) Suppose that $f:\Bbb Z\to  \Bbb Z$ is a one-to-one function. Define a function $g:\Bbb Z\to  \Bbb Z$ by: for all integers $x$, $g(x)= -f(x)$. Prove that $g$ is also one-to-one.

b) Suppose $f:\Bbb Z\to  \Bbb Z$ is an onto function. Define a function $g:\Bbb Z\to  \Bbb Z$ by: for all integers $x$, $g(x) = f(x) + 4$. Prove that $g$ is also onto.

c) Suppose that $f$ and $g$ are one-to-one functions from $\Bbb Z$ to $\Bbb Z$. Define the function $h: \Bbb Z\to \Bbb Z$ by $h(x)=f(x)+g(x)$ for all integers $x$. Must $h$ be one-to-one? Give a proof or counterexample.

Comment: "Where to begin" is by making sure you understand all the terms in the questions. Do you know what $\bf Z$ is? what $f:{\bf Z}\to{\bf Z}$ means? what a one-to-one function is? what an onto function is?

Answer (score 1):

For $(a)$, note that $m=n\iff -m=-n$.

For $(b)$, you know $f$ is onto, so for each $m$ there exists $n$ such that $f(n)=m$. But then for each $m+4$ there exists $n$ such that $g(n)=f(n)+4=m+4$, and $h(m)=m+4$ is a bijection in the integers.

For $(c)$, try $f(n)=-n$ and $g(n)= n$.